# off band with Ambient Occlusion and Environmental lighting in Blender render?

Tags: texturing

Im trying to tweek the ambient occlusion factor with environmental lighting on and I get an odd band across suzzanne.

Is that normal?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.0 is probably too high for your scene.Remember AO is specifically for shadowing in tight spaces, not large shadows.